# Mocha test at kill() function

Tags: truffle, truffle-test, selfdestruct, mocha

How to test with Mocha and Chai that a call at the `kill()` function of a Smart Contract (i.e., which does the `selfdestruct`) has gone right?

Comment: you can emit an event an check it in the test or call a function after selfdestruct and check for exception

Comment: I tried to catch the exception with https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/test/helpers/expectThrow.js, but when I try to call a function (after the kill function) i got 'Error: Attempting to run transaction which calls a contract function, but recipient address 0x345ca3e014aaf5dca488057592ee47305d9b3e10 is not a contract address'

Comment: as the contract is destructed you can no more call its functions hence the exception

Answer (score 1):

You can confirm that the bytecode has been zeroed out. Use the `web3.eth.getCode(yourContractAddress)` explained [here](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#getcode).

- before `selfdestruct`, you get the proper code, like `0x6040...`
- after `selfdestruct`, you get `0x`

Of course, as mentioned by Ignacio and Badr, you can, and should, also test that the side actions have been executed correctly:

- the expected event was emitted
- the correct recipient received the balance

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the funds of the contract have been sent to the given address.